# Slow with extra monitors

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, usb, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

I am currently on Ubuntu 20.04 which is also dual-booted to windows 10. I have an AMD machine with Radeon RX550/550 Series graphics. Normally the machine works fine but when I plug in a usb-vga adapater in order to run a second display, the second monitor works, but the whole computer becomes very laggy (both the one plugged in via hdmi and the one with the adapter one). When I boot to windows, the monitors work fine without any lag. Here is the `lsusb` output:

[image: lsusb]

If anyone knows how to make this system work without the lag, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Output from `free`:
[image: Free]

Comment: Have you installed the DisplayLink drivers?

Comment: How much RAM/swap space?  `free` will tell you.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I do have the DisplayLink drivers

Comment: @waltinator I added the output above. Thanks!